# Form Authentication in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have a Form Authentication in MVC application. The login page is hosted in the below url. The code is :

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="http://localhost:100/MyLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f" name="adCookie" protection="All" timeout="10" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
    </authentication>
```

My App_Start has following RouteConfig file

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

So I gave the authentication redirect in Index Action of Home controller like below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);

            //return View();
        }   
    }
```

But, how will I now be able to go to my applications required Controller and View after it is been authenticated?

Comment: It looks like that is what the ReturnUrl parameter in the MyLogin.aspx url is probably for if I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use the default url.

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index"/>
```

And then use a redirect after authentication similar to :

```
//Request is authenticated go to some url
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
```

Or

```
//Request is authenticated go to the page that caused the 302 redirect
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(myTicket.UserName,createPersisentToken);
```

In your MVC controller, it would go something like this.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //The response will not hit here if not authenticated
        //return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
        return View();
    }  
} 

[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller     
{
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    { 
        if(DoSomeLoginAndSetAuthenticationTicket())
             FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(...);
        return View(model);    
    } 
}
```

Comment: What does the else part do?

Comment: Redirects back to the requested resource that forced the login redirect.

Comment: So return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl); is not required in the Index action? Sorry, I didnt understand.

Comment: Can you show the entire Index Action code? Like redirect to authentication login page and after sucessfull go to My Controller

Comment: Generally, you only want to redirect to login or redirect after login. That redirect in your Index page will always redirect to login, even when the user is authenticated, don't know if that is what you want. Since you have forms active, the user will be redirected to your login when they hit Index when un-authenticated, however, after login/authentication, you need to send the request somewhere.

Comment: Added example controller code. The [Authorize] attribute can be used in your controllers.

Comment: localhost:100/MyLogin.aspx is my login page. So when I do like  ` return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);`  it goes to login page and ends there. Not going to my other controllers.

Comment: You have to set the Authentication Ticket and then redirect to the default.